# Constructing an example so that that the natural map is not a surjection.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have read many variants of proofs where $c_{0}$ is not reflexive by depending on a separability argument. I would like to instead show this by directly exhibiting a function in $c_{0}^{**}$ which cannot be represented by the natural map.

So far, I have shown that the following map 
$$f_{\kappa}: c_{00}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}, \quad f_{\kappa}(\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_{n}\kappa_{n} $$
where $c_{00}$ is the space of sequences that have all but finitely many entries equal to zero. Actually determines a bounded linear functional on $c_{0}$ for each choice of $\kappa \in \ell^{1}$ and that this is an isometric isomorphism from $\ell^{1}$ to $c_{0}^{*}$.

I think that I should now define a map $\psi\in c_{0}^{**}$ by $$\psi: c_{0}^{**}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}, \quad \psi(f_{\kappa}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\kappa_{n}$$ for $\kappa \in \ell^{1}$ and show that this action cannot be represented by the natural map. I would like to now argue that since $f_{\kappa}$ is a bounded linear functional on $c_{0}$, to consider

$$\psi(f_{\kappa}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\kappa_{n} = f_{\kappa}(\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\kappa_{n}\xi_{n}$$

and conclude that the natural map is not a surjection onto $c_{0}^{**}$ since the only $\xi$ which would make the above equation hold for all $\kappa \in \ell^{1}$ is the sequence of all $1$'s which is not in $c_{0}$.

I suspect something is wrong with this argument near the end but I am having trouble spotting the error.

I have two reasons for my suspicion.

1) The argument that $\xi = (1,1,\dots)$ seems tenuous at best.

2) Reading similar proofs elsewhere online usually involves using a result I am not familiar with that asserts the existence of a bounded linear functional $L$ with certain properties such as $L(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is $\psi(f_\kappa) = f_\kappa(\xi)$ has to hold for all $\kappa \in \ell^1$. In particular, it has to hold for $\kappa = \delta_n = \{\delta_{ni}\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ for each $n$, where $\delta_{ni}$ is the Kronecker delta.